# Pegar os menores valores de um count usando group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, group-by

Salve galera, tenho o seguinte problema... A consulta abaixo está quase perfeita, porém ela está gerando IDs repetidos, o que eu necessito é o menor valor do count de cada ID.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado ideal seria:

```
ID  |  COUNT
1      1
2      0
3      11
4      0
5      0
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Já experimentou retirar o `apdr.id_antibiotic_prescription` do `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Tentei sim, o resultado fica MUITO parecido do esperado porém ele pega o MAIOR valor do count...

`ID  |  COUNT
1      2
2      0
3      11
4      4
5      3`

Comment: [**Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas - Postar código como imagem**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-nÃo-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a cláusula `WITH` para reutilizar a sua `query` e trazer apenas o maior resultado do `COUNT`:

```
WITH quantidade AS (
  [SUA QUERY]
)
SELECT q1.*
  FROM quantidade q1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM quantidade q2
                   WHERE q2.id = q1.id
                     AND q2.count < q1.count)
```

---

> [`SELECT` in `WITH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html%20SELECT%20in%20WITH)
>
> The basic value of SELECT in WITH is to break down complicated queries into simpler parts.

Em tradução livre:

> O objetivo básico do SELECT dentro do WITH é quebrar quries complicadas em partes mais simples.

Comment: Amigo, não tenho palavras pra te agradecer! Eu estava a muito tempo quebrando a cabeça com isso... aliás eu nem conhecia esse comando with, enfim, obrigado :D